# Inlining style for Select multiple

Tags: html, css, select, styles

I want change the default style for a select multiple html tag.
I need apply an inline-block style and align center for the options, but when i apply this styles, the options don't break to a new line.

```
<select name="select" id="select" multiple size="3">
  <option value="1">option 1</option>
  <option value="2">option 2</option>
  <option value="3">option 3</option>
  <option value="4">option 4</option>
  <option value="5">option 5</option>
  <option value="6">option 6</option>
<select/>


select {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow;
  display: block;
}


option {
  width: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

here is the code:
https://codepen.io/gpuente/pen/NXeoRN

The box 1 is the select, and the box 2 is the result that i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add white-space:normal in your select

```
select {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background: yellow;
  display: block;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

https://codepen.io/RACCH/pen/ypGwNq